# How to fix the page position when I resize my HTA

Tags: javascript, html, css, hta

We are using HTAs to display detailed reporting information (about our automated tests). The HTA can become multiple page lengths. It works great for our users, but I have a usability issue: When a user has scrolled to a certain position in the report (say, teststep 42) and the user maximizes or resizes the HTA window, the user looses his current position in the report (he had jumped to teststep 32 for example) and has to scroll to the correct position again.

How can I fix the page position, so resizing the HTA window does not affect it?

I know, it is possible to use min-width etc. but the layout of the HTA is mend to vary in size and/or wrapping around the corner. The only thing I want is that the same information is directly visible on the screen after resizing. Is that possible?

Comment: sorry for the knob question but what is HTA?

Comment: @lbu: Hypertext Terminal Application: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

Comment: See the comment of Kooilnc. The advantage of an HTA above a HTML in a private environment (you can't use it over the internet) is the mark up through HTML and CSS, and code flexibility by combining VBScript and Javascript. Thereby it is a read only type, so a report can still be created (appended) while users can open and read it.

Comment: It's just HTML Application, not "Hypertext Terminal Application".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [scrollTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property of an element to know how far someone has scrolled down in the page.

Use the [onscroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536966%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event of the containing [div](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) element to record the value of that property each time scrolling occurs.

Then use some sort of "after resize" event to set the scrollTop property to the last recorded value. I haven't tracked down which [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533051%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) does this yet, but I'm sure there is something that will work.

Comment: That can be a solution. Creative, but it seems a lot hassle for a simple problem. Maybe I can find the IE version of MozAfterRepaint for the event.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the page exists of lots of elements (inheritance of the past) it is difficult to focus on the correct element. And to refactor the whole lot to just take away a minor annoyance was a bridge too far.
Allthough, it seems a good answer that could perfectly work in a simpler situation, so I gave you the credits you deserve after all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make the hta window unresizable.

```
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="Roll"
    APPLICATIONNAME="Roll" 
    BORDER="dialog"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    SCROLLFLAT="yes"
    CAPTION="yes"
    SELECTION="no"
    INNERBORDER="no"
    ICON=""
    SCROLL="no"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal" />
```

Comment: That would do it, but unfortunately it is not an option because I want 'resizing' as a feature.